# Which border radius for a round button?

Tags: html, css

I wanna create a responsive button so I cannot use "px" values for the border radius. If I try to use "%" values I never get to the format which I want. Basically the same button but instead of `border-radius=100px;` something responsive with "%".

Following a snippet.

```css
.button-in-main-box{
    background-color: #04AA6D;
    border:1px solid ;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 100px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span class = button-in-main-box>Löse Aufgabe</span>
```

Comment: What should it respond to? Font size? If so, have you taken a look at em and rem?

Comment: You can do responsive with px, it all depends how your button is going to be responsive. Like is the height going to change? If not then you can keep the current solution. Personally I use rem for most units but that depends as seedy say how is it going to respond.

Comment: there is no fully responsive css-only solution in an easy way. If the height is not fixed in some value (may it be pxl, em or rem) you wont be able to set a border-radius for 180 degree border. Setting a borderradius in % will apply it to width and height. So in your case it would be oval. THe JS solution would be to get the height of the element and apply the border-radius according to that.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you `border-radius: 5%/100%;`

There are more details about it in here: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#the-border-radius

Comment: Really nice of you to point the specific part of the W3C spec ! ✌️

Answer (score 1):

Try using `rem`. It is responsive tho.

```css
.button-in-main-box{
    background-color: #04AA6D;
    border:1px solid ;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 20rem;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span class = button-in-main-box>Löse Aufgabe</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using **rem** or **em** unit. Rem is relative to the root font size of your html document while em is relative to the font size of the element or nearest parent.

```css
.button-in-main-box{
    background-color: #04AA6D;
    border:1px solid ;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 15px 0;
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 6.25rem;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span class = button-in-main-box>Löse Aufgabe</span>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.

Answer (score 1):

The `border-radius` property defines the radius of the element's corners and it sometimes take more than one value depending on what you want to achieve,

A simple rule

```
/* If one value is set, `radius` applies to all 4 corners. */
    border-radius: 15px;

/* If two values are set, the first applies to top-left and 
   bottom-right corner, the second applies to top-right and 
   bottom-left corner. */
   border-radius: 15px 15px;

/* Three values: The second value applies to top-right and 
   also bottom-left. */
   border-radius: 15px 15px 15px;

/* Four values apply to the top-left, top-right, bottom- 
     right, bottom-left corner */
   border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
```

Keep in mind that , `percentages` , refer to corresponding `dimension` of the `border box`.

You may specify the value of `border-radius` in `percentages`. This is particularly useful when wanting to create a `circle` or `elipse` shape,

```
/* create a circle */
border-radius: 50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the value of `border-radius` depends on the `height` of the button which includes `height` + `padding`.

You may set and use those two value within a css `var(--myCssVar)` and `calc()`. It will adapt itself the value to set to `border-radius.`

examples:

```css
.button-in-main-box {
  /* update using css var to calculate border-radius according to height + padding */
  --height: 15px;
  --padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: content-box;/*keep it that way */
  height: var(--height);
  padding: var(--padding) 0;
  border-radius: calc(var(--height) + var(--padding));
  
  /* original op's rules */
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 40%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span class="button-in-main-box">Löse Aufgabe</span>
<hr> give it a different height and padding via a reset of CSS var() used

<span class="button-in-main-box" style="--height:30px;--padding:40px">Löse Aufgabe</span> what about font-size and em ?

<span class="button-in-main-box" style="font-size:10px;--height:1.5em;--padding:0.5em">Löse Aufgabe</span>
```

ressources:

- CSS variable

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var()
>
> The `var()` CSS function can be used to insert the value of a custom property (sometimes called a "CSS variable") instead of any part of a value of another property.

- CSS `calc()` function

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc()
>
> The `calc()` CSS function lets you perform calculations when specifying CSS property values. It can be used anywhere a `<length>`, `<frequency>`, `<angle>`, `<time>`, `<percentage>`, `<number>`, or `<integer>` is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution `border-radius: 50%;` is only good for fully circular button where the base box shape is square, but the question is more on making only the two ends of the button rounded (or semi circles, to be specific) considering the button is a rectangular box.

As one of the answers mentioned, the calc() method by which you try to calculate the height of the button and then set the radius as half of it appears most logical. However, it is a complex solution.

A simpler solution is to set **a very high value** to the **border-radius** property. Again high values such as 100px, 200px, etc. can still be inadequate in some cases if buttons are quite big. So a common practice is to set `border-radius: 100vh;`. It will work as long as the height of the button is 200vh or bigger. And we typically don't make buttons that are bigger than viewport and which cannot be fully seen without scrolling the page.

I knew this practice works, but faced with the given question, I tried to explore the reason, could not find a direct answer anywhere; but from adding different pieces of the puzzle, I come to the following conclusion:

Placing one value (instead of four) for border-radius is a shorthand, and it euates all the four values based on the given value. And thus, `border-radius: 10px;` converts to `border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;` - where each value represents each of the corners (starting from top-left and going clockwise). But this is not the real longhand. Instead, the real longhand version is something like this: `border-radius: 25px 10px 15px 20px / 10px 10px 15px 20px;` - in which the first set of four values are the horizontal radii of the four corners, and the second set (that comes after '/') represents the vertical radii of the corners.

Just like when one value is given instead of four, the value is equated to all four places; likewise, if we skip one side of '/', the other side is equated with the given values. Thus the logic tries to equate the horizontal radius and the vertical radius of any corner if they are not separately specified.

When we apply % values, they are bound to local width and height. For a button box that has 200 px width and 40 px height, specifying `border-radius: 50%;` makes each type of radius independently bound - i.e., the horizontal radius becomes 50% of width = 100px, and the vertical radius is calculated as 50% of the height = 20px. It results in an elliptical shape.

But with global dimensions such as vh (viewport height), the specification is first evaluated in a pixel value and then equated for all. But since a pixel value greater than half of the height is meaningless (it will make two adjacent corner curves overlap - which is not allowed), it is the minimum of the two values - the specified value and half of the height. Then that same minimum value is copied to all the places. Thus our button gets a converted spec of `border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px / 20px 20px 20px 20px;` and we get the desired shape of a button retains the rectangular form but with only the two ends looking like half circles.

**Disclaimer:** The above is what I can derive from what I read from various sources on border-radius. Please update me with any fallacies in my thought or any other direct explanation of this phenomenon.

Comment: Overall, your answer provides a good technical explanation of the issue and presents a simple solution to achieve the desired result. One minor suggestion would be to include some code snippets or visual aids to help illustrate your explanations.

Answer (score 0):

We now have the option of units based on container size.

[**W3C Spec**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-contain-3/#container-lengths)

> Container query length units specify a length relative to the dimensions of a query container.

Thus for an end border-radius we can use the container height.

```css
div {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 75px;
  background: lightblue;
  border-radius: 50cqh;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```